# How to use the OCR (TesseractOCR) php library

Tags: php, ocr

I had clone git library of OCR using this link .

```
git clone git://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php.git
```

then simply i include the required file by following this [example](http://thiagoalessio.me/tesseractocr-for-php-on-windows/)

here is the example code which i m trying to run

```
require_once './src/TesseractOCR.php';
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('text.png');
$text = $tesseract->recognize();
echo "The recognized text is:", $text;
```

But always it fires a fatal Error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method TesseractOCR::recognize()

**Edit** I tried to use `run()` instead of `recognize()`

```
require_once './src/TesseractOCR.php';
$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('text.png');
$text = $tesseract->run();
var_dump($text);
echo PHP_EOL, "The recognized text is:", $text, PHP_EOL;
```

Then result is : `string(0) "" The recognized text is:`

I had tried my best to find some appropriate solution  but failed to find some authentic solution

Comment: There does not seem to be a `recognize()` function in that class. What happens when you add `var_dump($tesseract)` after this line: `$tesseract = new TesseractOCR('text.png');`

Comment: Try `run()` in place of `recognize()` and see if that works. There is a documentation here: https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Comment: $tesseract  i had var_dump this instance of class is available . And run is also is function . But run did give me any result as per exception.

Comment: In that case, maybe the library is not able to recognize the text in the png file. You might wanna try the updated code with some other png files and see if that works.

Comment: sure give me a mint thanks @Maximus2012

Comment: @Maximus2012 still the same result .its giving a empty string in return.

Comment: Instead of using `new TesseractOCR('text.png');` try `new TesseractOCR('http://www.ghulmil.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/beautiful-black-text-wallpaper-for-computer.jpg');` it will confirm if the fault is in file path

Comment: still empty result . @Sami

Comment: What's your TesseractOCR version?

Comment: "version": "1.0.0-RC"  with "license": "Apache-2.0",  .

Comment: You're talking about `tesseract-ocr-for-php` package, that is just a PHP wrapper, I ask about TesseractOCR itself (a program written in c++ that you installed in your OS).

Comment: sorry i couldn't  find it

Comment: execute `tesseract -v` in command line/terminal/bash/shell/whatever :)

Comment: do i need to install its binary too ? if yes then please provide me the binary link . Thanks

Comment: First line in installation instructions on package's page: `First of all, make sure you have Tesseract OCR installed. (v3.03 or greater)` ;-) Go here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Comment: your second edit works fine.It prints text result output in a file called "stdout.txt" in same directory as php file in my case instead of returning in var $text.

Answer (score 2):

This sample code probably comes from [this article](http://thiagoalessio.me/tesseractocr-for-php-on-windows/) or some similar. But I can see that it's over 1,5 year old and apparently it's outdated.

Take a look at their [github's page](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php). It looks like it's `run()` instead of `recognize()` right now:

```
<?php
echo (new TesseractOCR('german.png'))
    ->run();
```

Comment: run give me empty result Please read my question again i had made a edit . thanks

Comment: Have you tried one of sample png files used as examples on their github page? That should make clear if it's file's fault.

Comment: I had tried some other files too but same result . @dragoste

Comment: I didn't ask about "*some other files*". I asked if you have tried sample PNG files **used on their Github page** as examples?

Comment: It prints text result output in a file called "stdout.txt" in same directory as php file in my case.