# OCR wrapper for php

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I am using [this](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) for ocr. This is wrapper for Tesseract ocr(I previosly installed Tesseract itself).

At first i dowloaded it via composer and followed examples in repo and also several posts on SO itself. And all can show is in network tab `failed to load response data`.

My alternate approaches is that i tried downloading repo itself, then tried to call it from my `index.php` which for test purposes is situated in same folder where class `TesseractOCR` is. I tried with images in repo and also tried with black letters on white background images with simple text.

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127736/how-to-use-the-ocr-tesseractocr-php-library) post looks promising, but i'm unsure where OP's file with example code is residing...

```
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
//or//require "TesseractOCR.php";//if it's in the same dir as test.php
$content = new TesseractOCR('text.png');
$text = $content->run();
echo $text;
```

Did i miss something obvious? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT1:** I tried using in win powershell cli. By putting `text.png` in directory where tesseract is installed, then calling shell with administrator privileges, subsequently typing in it `tesseract text.png output` which creates `output.txt` in same directory with recognized text from that image.
So tesseract its working, my implementation with php wrapper is not.

**EDIT2:**
Forgot to add, page itself shows:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Not sure why it happens.

**Edit3:**

My code:

```
try{
    
    //use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
    require "./vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/src/TesseractOCR.php";
    echo $temp;//It's value is set in TesseractOCR.php
    $content = new TesseractOCR('text1.png');
    $text = $content->run();
    echo $text;
    
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Value set in `$temp` variable is visible through state file path, so why `TesseractOCR`class itself isn't?

**Edit4:**
Even if i put absolute path to `TesseractOCR.php` which holds class, in include statement, it doesn't work.
It throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TesseractOCR' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\index.php on line 10
This is TesseractOCR.//echoed text from file that holds TesseractOCR class.
```

Inclusion path:

```
include ("C:/xampp/htdocs/myocr/vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/src/TesseractOCR.php");
```

If i use(which is suggested in repo readme, `use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;`, then it throws:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\index.php on line 10
```

My question is: How it hits test message, but won't hit `TesseractOCR` class?

**EDIT5:**
If i `require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";` , it throws:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractNotFoundException: Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. Make sure you have Tesseract OCR installed on your system: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract The current $PATH is C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Eddie\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php:48 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\TesseractOCR.php(26): thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\FriendlyErrors::checkTesseractPresence('tesseract') #1 C:\xampp\ht in C:\xampp\htdocs\myocr\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php on line 48
```

Btw, i added its patch to env variable:
[image: envpath]

Comment: Any error messages, partial results, dumps, anything that would help us identify the problem? Try to surround your code in `try { ... } catch($e) { var_dump($e); }` block and post the error msg here, if any.

Comment: Also, make sure your text.png exists (`file_exists('text.png');`) in your current working dir (check with `getcwd();`)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' No. I tried dumping variable that holds `new TesseractOCR('text1.png')`. Nothing, just network message "failed to load response data"..

Comment: Try to catch and display error with `try { ... } catch ...` block. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Tried it. Nothing new. I edited post, take a gander at it again.

Comment: Hmm, can you check if `thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR` class is loaded? Either with composer's `require '/vendor/autoload.php';` or manually. Also, HTTP 500 most probably means your PHP script throws an error somewhere. You need to catch or display it, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/3290062

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Display_errors is on and it says: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TesseractOCR' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testocr\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testocr\index.php on line 7` which is surprising considering that i put whole path in the require("./vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/src/TesseractOCR.php") in my index.php

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere :-) I'd recommend installing the composer package and using composer's autoloading (`require './vendor/autoload.php';`)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' As i said, i already did it.

Comment: If it still throws the same fatal error, then you must've done it wrong somehow. You may try checking your relative paths exist under your cwd.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' When i put `getcwd()` in a variable and then echo that variable in index.php which is well outside of `TesseractOCR` class, it says: `c/xampp/htdocs/myocr` i.e. my project directory. I previously put `require "./vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/src/TesseractOCR.php";`.

Comment: Does `c:/xampp/htdocs/myocr/vendor/autoload.php` exist?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Yes.

Comment: Can you `require` this file instead of TesseractOCR.php and see if the error message changes?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Yes. See edit.

Comment: From the last error message, C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR is still missing from $PATH environment variable. You might wanna restart your XAMP or maybe the whole system, since it's Windows :-) Then see wether it works or the error changes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!. My problem occurs that i didn't know about autoloaders in php.
Link that helped me is [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649).

My project structure is this:

1. Created project folder myocr.
2. After previous, downloaded latest stable version of [Tesseract](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/) and installed it.
3. Depending on your system, you may be required to add value to your system env variable. You need to do that here

[image: panel]

then

[image: p1]

then

[image: p2]

then

[image: p3]

I'm assuming it self explanatory with images provided.

4. Next is getting [TesseractOCR](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) via composer:

```
    composer require thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr
```

5. Finally, before using code sample in repo, you need to call autoloader.
   Index.php:

```
    require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');//<-This!
    use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
    
    $content = new TesseractOCR('text1.png');
    $text = $content->run();
    echo $text;
```

This worked for me. Crucial thing to look after is directory structure.
`localhost > myocr > index.php` with its code, and after using composer you'll get vendor dir. and it's content. Image path in new `TesseractOCR('text1.png');` is directory where both `index.php` and image are located.